# Percentage of an Occurrence in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Looked, but only found down voted questions with no good answers.

I'm trying to find the percentage of an occurrence in SQL Server. A simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
 ID    NAME   FAVORITE_COLOR
------------------------------------
  1    Jim        Blue
  2    Tom        Green
  3    Rob        Yellow
  4    Kev        Blue
  5    Kim        Green
  6    Bev        Blue
```

I can count how many of each, that's easy.

```
SELECT 
    favorite_color, COUNT(favorite_color) AS totals 
FROM 
    color_prefs 
GROUP BY 
    favorite_color
```

That'll tell me 3 people like Blue (etc). What I can't figure out how to do is get the percent. I want to know that 50% of people like Blue. I tried the below, but SQL totally hated it:

```
SELECT 
    favorite_color, 
    COUNT(favorite_color) / SUM(COUNT(favorite_color)) AS color_percent 
FROM 
    color_prefs 
GROUP BY 
    favorite_color
```

I get the error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Obviously, I could make PHP figure this out for me, but I there's got to be a way to do this in SQL without subqueries, right?

Comment: so you want a query without subquery?

Comment: In the end I don't care, but ideally without. The real query is a bit more complex because I'm joining two tables and limiting to a date range... But that's so specific to me, it would never help anyone else with this same sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways..first way is not so efficient, but if your table does not contain a lot of rows, then it should be ok..

```
select favorite_color,count(favorite_color)*100/(select count(*) from a)
from color_prefs
group by favorite_color
```

This is the second way and is more efficient..

```
select favorite_color,count(favorite_color)*100/sum(count(*)) over()
from color_prefs
group by favorite_color
```

check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/177157/10)

Comment: Giving the answer to this question because it's a bit more complete. It does seem like I need to learn about over() to understand how this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions:

```
Select color, count(*),
       Count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over ()
From color_prefs
Group by color;
```

Comment: That does it. But why/how does it do it? I guess what I'd like to know is where I should look to find out more about what I was doing wrong OR what this is doing right.  Maybe start with over()?

Comment: A good place to start is the documentation or articles on the subject:  http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1.